Gitlab "git pull" job not updating repo
I am using a self hosted instance of gitlab and scheduling a job on my runner to pull code from a remote github repo. the job completes and, from all indications, has no issues. however when i look at the repo from the frontend there are no changes. BUT in my RH server i can see the pulled/updated changes from the remote repo have been brought in.
the job output gives me this as my pwd
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/U9qyH6x1t/0/{username}/repo-github/.git/

but nothing in the ui shows that it's updated. when i navigate there on the backend i can see all the changes just fine.
why is the gitlab ui not reflecting what im seeing on the backend?
full job output (some redundant parts of the script from testing)
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes...
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/U9qyH6x1t/0/{username}/repo-github/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 25f3ad5a as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 25f3ad5 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
$ pwd
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/U9qyH6x1t/0/{username}/repo-github
$ ls -al
total 76
drwxrwxr-x. 10 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Apr  2 14:38 .
drwxrwxr-x.  4 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    46 Apr  2 14:38 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  4 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Apr  2 14:38 actions
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     0 Apr  2 14:38 add
drwxrwxr-x.  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   199 Apr  2 14:38 aliases
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  3705 Apr  2 14:38 CHANGES.md
drwxrwxr-x.  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    24 Apr  2 14:38 .circleci
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  1949 Apr  2 14:38 config.schema.yaml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     0 Apr  2 14:38 git
drwxrwxr-x.  5 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   119 Apr  2 14:38 .git
drwxrwxr-x.  3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    23 Apr  2 14:38 .github
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   561 Apr  2 14:38 github.yaml.example
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  1045 Apr  2 14:38 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   458 Apr  2 14:38 .gitlab-ci.yml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  2156 Apr  2 14:38 icon.png
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 11357 Apr  2 14:38 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   336 Apr  2 14:38 pack.yaml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  5775 Apr  2 14:38 README.md
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     8 Apr  2 14:38 requirements-tests.txt
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    62 Apr  2 14:38 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x.  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    50 Apr  2 14:38 rules
drwxrwxr-x.  2 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    78 Apr  2 14:38 sensors
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner    14 Apr  2 14:38 st2-test2
-rw-rw-r--.  1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  3366 Apr  2 14:38 st2-vm.txt
drwxrwxr-x.  3 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  4096 Apr  2 14:38 tests
$ git config --global user.name '{username}'
$ git config --global user.email '{email}'
$ git pull https://{username}:{gh_token}@github.com/repo-github
From https://github.com/repo-github
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .github/workflows/st2-pull.yml | 13 ++++++++-----
 st2-test2                      |  2 +-
 2 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
$ echo "test" > READ.ME
Job succeeded

.gitlab-ci.yml
st2-pull:
  # variables:
  #   GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  # stage: deploy
  script:
        - git fetch --all 
        - git reset --hard origin/master
        - pwd
        - ls -al
        - git config --global user.name '{username}'
        - git config --global user.email '{email}'
        - git pull https://{username}:{gh_token}@github.com/repo-github
        - echo "test" > READ.ME
        #100

